# Equivalent of the Solaris "df -t" command on Linux?

Tags: linux, df

The `df -t` command on Linux does not display the number of files like it does on Solaris. Is there any equivalent command on Linux?

My script is like this

```
for i in /opt/aa /opt/aa/data /opt/aa/bb; do echo -n "$i "; df -t $i | awk ' { if ( NR==1) F=$(NF-1) ; if ( NR==2) print $(NF-1) - F }'; done
```

Output :

```
/opt/aa 397375
/opt/aa/data 24134317
/opt/aa/bb/oracle 529
```

I can see number of files in respective file systems
I would need similar command for linux, this above command is working fine with solaris ?

Comment: What exactly does the Solaris command show that you need? Not all Linux fans here know Solaris. What distribution and version are you using? That might be relevant.

Comment: also can you add an example of what output you like to have.

Comment: My script is like this 

    for i in /opt/aa /opt/aa/data /opt/aa/bb; do echo -n "$i "; df -t $i | awk ' { if ( NR==1) F=$(NF-1) ; if ( NR==2) print $(NF-1) - F }'; done

Output : 

    /opt/aa 397375
    /opt/aa/data 24134317
    /opt/aa/bb/oracle 529

I can see number of files in respective file systems
I would need similar command for linux, this above command is working fine with solaris ?

Answer (score 2):

Your command parses `df -t` output to compute the number of used inodes, i.e. roughly the number of files that have been created in the file system containing this directory.

Solaris only reports the total and free inodes:

```
Solaris # df -t /home/jlliagre
rpool1/export/home/jlliagre: 20775669 blocks 20775669 files
                      total: 69672960 blocks 20775865 files
```

On linux, the closer command is `df -i`. The `IUsed` column shows the number of used inodes and the `IFree` one shows the number of free inodes.

```
Linux # df -i
Filesystem            Inodes   IUsed   IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/root_vg-lv_root
                     1048576   57730  990846    6% /
```

So the Linux equivalent of your Solaris command would be:

```
for i in /opt/aa /opt/aa/data /opt/aa/bb; do
    echo -n "$i "; df -i $i | awk 'NR > 1 {print $2}'
done
```

Note that if `/opt/aa`, `/opt/aa/data` and `/opt/aa/bb` belong to the same file system, the number reported will be the same for each of these directories, which might not be what you want.

Comment: does number of inod mean number of file ?

Comment: @Kiwy, yes though that depends what you mean by file. For instance, some of the inodes reported by `df` will have no entry in any directory and some will have more than one entry (hard links). That's probably the same with Solaris `df -t`.

Comment: See also `stat -fc '%c-%d' /opt/aa | bc` (assuming GNU `stat`).

Comment: I believe you mean `IUsed`, which gives the used inodes, `IFRee` gives the free ones. In any case, this gives the inodes (files + directories + devices, essentially) in the *filesystem*, not under the directory, which seems to be what OP wants.

Comment: @vonbrand I indeed meant IUsed. I just updated my reply to clarify what the OP script does and provide an equivalent script under Solaris.

Answer (score 0):

On linux I would use :

```
 find /opt/aa           -type f -xdev| wc -l
 find /opt/aa/data      -type f -xdev | wc -l
 find /opt/aa/bb/oracle -type f -xdev | wc -l
```

But that could be unreliable if you are not root.
`find folder -type f` will print the list of all your file in a folder. `-mount` is use to not search into mount point and limitate to the current filesystem.
`| wc -l` will count the lines of find command.

<strike>I think this command is not available because the file system type is different on linux.</strike>

Comment: Strictly speaking, that's counting the lines in the name of all directory entries (omits `.` and `..` though), not the files or inodes. `-xdev` is the standard name for `-mount`.